# Unable to select Angular Material chip/chips and indicate that this chip has been selected?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am not able to achieve chip selection and indicate to the user that this chip has been selected.

I have the following html template code:

```
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">
  <mat-chip selected (selectionChange)="onSelectedChip($event)" [selectable]="true"  *ngFor="let size of sizes | sizeEnumToSize">{{ size }}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Initially I am just trying to have all of the chips be in the selected state. I would expect the chip to visually change its state to show user it has been selected. I have also tried doing [selected]="true" but this results in the same normal list as expected.

What am I missing from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are true: there is no indication whether a single chip is selected or not by using only `[selectable]="true"`. I guess, you need a `boolean` value to indicate the state of each chip.

Something like:

```
// TS
sizes = [{ selected: true, name: 'Foo' }, { selected: true, name: 'Bar' }];

// HTML
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let size of sizes"
            [selected]="size.selected"
            (click)="size.selected = !size.selected">{{size.name}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: is it up to the developer to change the visual representation of a selected chip?

Comment: By using `[selected]="size.selected"` the color of the accordant chip should change. You could also think about something like `[color]="size.selected ? 'accent' : 'primary'"`.